# Query using 128GB of RAM

Tags: mysql

I've been struggling with a large query which I have yet to run once successfully. Each time I run it, it was showing 'Killed' unexpectedly. Finally after looking into it, I see that the memory usage is going from 10GB to 128GB over a course of about 20-30 minutes before the process is killed and the memory restores to normal.

The EXPLAIN SELECT results [can be seen here](https://www.diigo.com/item/image/4nlmw/7ghu).

The query itself can be seen here:

```
SELECT
Import_AcesApplication_New.sku,
Import_AcesApplication_New.notes,
Parts.partterminologyname,
BaseVehicle.YearID,
Make.MakeName,
Model.modelname,
Submodel.SubmodelName,
CONCAT(EngineBase.Cylinders, ' Cyl ', EngineBase.Liter, 'L') as engine,
Positions.position,
BedLength.BedLength,
BedLength.BedLengthMetric,
BedType.BedTypeName,
BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoors,
BodyType.BodyTypeName,
FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemName,
BrakeABS.BrakeABSName,
DriveType.DriveTypeName,
EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName,
EngineVIN.EngineVINName,
Valves.ValvesPerEngine,
EngineBase.Liter,
EngineBase.CC,
EngineBase.CID,
EngineBase.Cylinders,
EngineBase.BlockType,
EngineBase.EngBoreIn,
EngineBase.EngBoreMetric,
EngineBase.EngStrokeIn,
EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric,
FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName,
Aspiration.AspirationName,
CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName,
FuelType.FuelTypeName,
IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
EngineMfr.MfrName,
EngineVersion.EngineVersion,
PowerOutput.HorsePower,
PowerOutput.KilowattPower,
SpringType.SpringTypeName,
SteeringType.SteeringTypeName,
SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemName,
TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeName,
TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeeds,
TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCode,
TransElecControlled.ElecControlled,
TransmissionMfr.MfrName,
WheelBase.WheelBase,
WheelBase.WheelBaseMetric,
VehicleType.VehicleTypeName,
VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupName
FROM
Import_AcesApplication_New
STRAIGHT_JOIN BaseVehicle ON Import_AcesApplication_New.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Parts ON Import_AcesApplication_New.part_type_id=Parts.PartTerminologyID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Make ON BaseVehicle.MakeID=Make.MakeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Model ON BaseVehicle.ModelID=Model.ModelID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Vehicle ON Import_AcesApplication_New.base_vehicle_id=Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Submodel ON Vehicle.SubmodelID=Submodel.SubmodelID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToBedConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToBedConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToBodyStyleConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToBodyStyleConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToBrakeConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToBrakeConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToDriveType ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToDriveType.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToSpringTypeConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToSteeringConfig ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToSteeringConfig.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToTransmission ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToTransmission.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleToWheelbase ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToWheelbase.VehicleID
STRAIGHT_JOIN EngineConfig ON VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID=EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN EngineBase ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID=EngineBase.EngineBaseID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Positions ON Import_AcesApplication_New.position_id=Positions.PositionID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BedConfig ON VehicleToBedConfig.BedConfigID=BedConfig.BedConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BedLength ON BedConfig.BedLengthID=BedLength.BedLengthID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BedType ON BedConfig.BedTypeID=BedType.BedTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BodyStyleConfig ON VehicleToBodyStyleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID=BodyStyleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BodyNumDoors ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyNumDoorsID=BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoorsID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BodyType ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyTypeID=BodyType.BodyTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BrakeConfig ON VehicleToBrakeConfig.BrakeConfigID=BrakeConfig.BrakeConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BrakeType FrontBrakeType ON BrakeConfig.FrontBrakeTypeID=FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BrakeType RearBrakeType ON BrakeConfig.RearBrakeTypeID=RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BrakeSystem ON BrakeConfig.BrakeSystemID=BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemID
STRAIGHT_JOIN BrakeABS ON BrakeConfig.BrakeABSID=BrakeABS.BrakeABSID
STRAIGHT_JOIN DriveType ON VehicleToDriveType.DriveTypeID=DriveType.DriveTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN EngineDesignation ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID=EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
STRAIGHT_JOIN EngineVIN ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID=EngineVIN.EngineVINID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Valves ON EngineConfig.ValvesID=Valves.Valvesid
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID=FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelDeliveryType ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID=FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelDeliverySubType ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID=FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelSystemControlType ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID=FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelSystemDesign ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID=FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Aspiration ON EngineConfig.AspirationID=Aspiration.AspirationID
STRAIGHT_JOIN CylinderHeadType ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID=CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN FuelType ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID=FuelType.FuelTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN IgnitionSystemType ON EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID=IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Mfr EngineMfr ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID=EngineMfr.MfrID
STRAIGHT_JOIN EngineVersion ON EngineConfig.EngineVersionID=EngineVersion.EngineVersionID
STRAIGHT_JOIN PowerOutput ON EngineConfig.PowerOutputId=PowerOutput.PowerOutputId
STRAIGHT_JOIN SpringType ON VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.SpringTypeConfigID=SpringType.SpringTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN SteeringConfig ON VehicleToSteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID=SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID
STRAIGHT_JOIN SteeringType ON SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID=SteeringType.SteeringTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN SteeringSystem ON SteeringConfig.SteeringSystemID=SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Transmission ON VehicleToTransmission.TransmissionID=Transmission.TransmissionID
STRAIGHT_JOIN TransmissionBase ON Transmission.TransmissionBaseID=TransmissionBase.TransmissionBaseID
STRAIGHT_JOIN TransmissionType ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionTypeID=TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN TransmissionNumSpeeds ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionNumSpeedsID=TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeedsID
STRAIGHT_JOIN TransmissionControlType ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionControlTypeID=TransmissionControlType.TransmissionControlTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN TransmissionMfrCode ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrCodeID=TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCodeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN ElecControlled TransElecControlled ON Transmission.TransmissionElecControlledID=TransElecControlled.ElecControlledID
STRAIGHT_JOIN Mfr TransmissionMfr ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrID=TransmissionMfr.MfrID
STRAIGHT_JOIN WheelBase ON VehicleToWheelbase.WheelbaseID=WheelBase.WheelBaseID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleType ON Model.VehicleTypeID=VehicleType.VehicleTypeID
STRAIGHT_JOIN VehicleTypeGroup ON VehicleType.VehicleTypeGroupId=VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupId
```

Is there anything I can do to optimize the query so that it finishes (without it chewing over 100GB of data)?

Thanks!

Comment: Any indexes on the dozens of tables?

Comment: you have 60 joins try to break down the query to simpler queries.

Comment: Hey there. Yes -- the tables all have indexes.

Comment: @SamD - I wish I could, but the JOINs are being used to map the values from these reference tables. The database structure is a standard for our industry.

Comment: STRAIGHT_JOIN tells mysql not to try optimizing join order and use order you specify in the query, but the order you specify seems to be mostly alphabetical. Still it probably won't change much, but you should use STRAIGHT_JOIN instead of a JOIN only if you are sure optimizer won't do it better.

Comment: As Sam D said, your query is quite complex. Try to split it in simpler queries... When I need to run complex queries, I split the problem down in intermediate temporary tables, and show only the final result. It's a "divide and conquer" strategy that has saved my neck many times.

Comment: How many records is this going to return? Have you tried to return just the result set based on 1 record of Import_AcesApplication_New? How long does that 1 record take? Maybe you can put some filters via the WHERE clause to reduce the number of records needed to be brought back.

Comment: The EXPLAIN SELECT link doesn't work

Comment: @AgRizzo I'm so sorry -- I just fixed the link.

Comment: @piotrm The path it was taking on it's own was incorrect, so I chose STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: No `WHERE`, you really want to load all database in RAM for what result?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Hey there -- the reason there is no where is because I have to pull all of the records. This is a query I'll run maybe once a month and is merely for data mapping purposes.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter Maybe you could range id by using some id from one table example `WHERE BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID >= 0 AND BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID <= 10000` and continue so until the end...

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using a table to hold the results you need and populating in in a number of steps.

for example with a simplified import table and lookup tables for make and model:

```
create table imp( sku int, notes varchar(20), make_id int, model_id int ) ;
create table make ( id int, make_name varchar(20) ) ;
create table model ( id int, model_name varchar(20) ) ;
```

create  a table for our result:

```
create table res( sku int, 
                  notes varchar(20), 
                  make varchar(20), 
                  model varchar(20) 
                );
```

stick in some sample data:

```
insert into imp values
( 1, 'blue ford focus', 2, 3 ), 
( 2,'green audi a4', 1, 2 ), 
( 3,'black audi a3', 1, 1 );

insert into make values( 1, 'audi'), (2,'ford');

insert into model values( 1, 'a3'), (2,'a4'), (3,'focus');
```

now get all the import data we are interested in

```
insert into res ( sku, notes ) select sku,notes from imp;
```

fix the make

```
update res 
join imp on res.sku = imp.sku
join make on imp.make_id = make.id
set res.make = make.make_name ;
```

and the model

```
update res 
join imp on res.sku = imp.sku
join model on imp.model_id = model.id
set res.model = model.model_name;
```

now get the result we wanted...

```
select * from res;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36fdc2/1

using techniques like this you may be able to break your query down into several queries, each of which will run.

**You would probably want to add an index to any relevant fields in the result table (sku in the above example)**

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are getting a Cartesian result as to all the different models and submodels and equipment for each vehicle.  Can you do a test, and add a WHERE clause to the very end for a single "Import_AcesApplication_New.base_vehicle_id" and see how many records get returned...

Then, give us a count of the total records in your "Import_AcesApplication_New" table.  It would probably be good to get the counts from ALL the tables as this is obviously choking your server.

In the mean-time, I am trying to work the query and will post back into more manageable pieces... but "STRAIGHT_JOIN" is only required ONCE at the top of your query, all the rest are normal joins.

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
     fields, fields, fields
   from
      yourTables
         JOIN Other Tables on ...
```

Also, in your original question that I answered and originally suggested the STRAIGHT_JOIN, I also suggested covering indexes for all your tables.  Did you create those indexes?

Ok, more to chew on...  I rewrote your query, just shuffled the order of joins to show the correlation of sub-components along the way..

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      IAN.sku,
      IAN.notes,
      Parts.partterminologyname,
      BaseVehicle.YearID,
      Make.MakeName,
      Model.modelname,
      Submodel.SubmodelName,
      CONCAT(EngineBase.Cylinders, ' Cyl ', EngineBase.Liter, 'L') as engine,
      Positions.position,
      BedLength.BedLength,
      BedLength.BedLengthMetric,
      BedType.BedTypeName,
      BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoors,
      BodyType.BodyTypeName,
      FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
      RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
      BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemName,
      BrakeABS.BrakeABSName,
      DriveType.DriveTypeName,
      EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName,
      EngineVIN.EngineVINName,
      Valves.ValvesPerEngine,
      EngineBase.Liter,
      EngineBase.CC,
      EngineBase.CID,
      EngineBase.Cylinders,
      EngineBase.BlockType,
      EngineBase.EngBoreIn,
      EngineBase.EngBoreMetric,
      EngineBase.EngStrokeIn,
      EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric,
      FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
      FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
      FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
      FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName,
      Aspiration.AspirationName,
      CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName,
      FuelType.FuelTypeName,
      IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
      EngineMfr.MfrName,
      EngineVersion.EngineVersion,
      PowerOutput.HorsePower,
      PowerOutput.KilowattPower,
      SpringType.SpringTypeName,
      SteeringType.SteeringTypeName,
      SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemName,
      TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeName,
      TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeeds,
      TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCode,
      TransElecControlled.ElecControlled,
      TransmissionMfr.MfrName,
      WheelBase.WheelBase,
      WheelBase.WheelBaseMetric,
      VehicleType.VehicleTypeName,
      VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupName
   FROM
      Import_AcesApplication_New IAN
         JOIN BaseVehicle 
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
            JOIN Make 
               ON BaseVehicle.MakeID = Make.MakeID
            JOIN Model 
               ON BaseVehicle.ModelID = Model.ModelID
               JOIN VehicleType 
                  ON Model.VehicleTypeID = VehicleType.VehicleTypeID
                  JOIN VehicleTypeGroup 
                     ON VehicleType.VehicleTypeGroupId = VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupId

         JOIN Parts 
            ON IAN.part_type_id = Parts.PartTerminologyID


         JOIN Vehicle 
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
            JOIN Submodel 
               ON Vehicle.SubmodelID = Submodel.SubmodelID

            JOIN VehicleToBedConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToBedConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN BedConfig 
                  ON VehicleToBedConfig.BedConfigID = BedConfig.BedConfigID
                  JOIN BedLength 
                     ON BedConfig.BedLengthID = BedLength.BedLengthID
                  JOIN BedType 
                     ON BedConfig.BedTypeID = BedType.BedTypeID

            JOIN VehicleToBodyStyleConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToBodyStyleConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN BodyStyleConfig 
                  ON VehicleToBodyStyleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID = BodyStyleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID
                  JOIN BodyNumDoors 
                     ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyNumDoorsID = BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoorsID
                  JOIN BodyType 
                     ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyTypeID = BodyType.BodyTypeID

            JOIN VehicleToBrakeConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToBrakeConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN BrakeConfig 
                  ON VehicleToBrakeConfig.BrakeConfigID = BrakeConfig.BrakeConfigID
                  JOIN BrakeType FrontBrakeType 
                     ON BrakeConfig.FrontBrakeTypeID = FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
                  JOIN BrakeType RearBrakeType 
                     ON BrakeConfig.RearBrakeTypeID = RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
                  JOIN BrakeSystem 
                     ON BrakeConfig.BrakeSystemID = BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemID
                  JOIN BrakeABS 
                     ON BrakeConfig.BrakeABSID = BrakeABS.BrakeABSID

            JOIN VehicleToDriveType 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToDriveType.VehicleID
               JOIN DriveType 
                  ON VehicleToDriveType.DriveTypeID = DriveType.DriveTypeID

            JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN EngineConfig 
                  ON VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID = EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
                  JOIN EngineBase 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID = EngineBase.EngineBaseID
                  JOIN EngineDesignation 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID = EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
                  JOIN EngineVIN 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID = EngineVIN.EngineVINID
                  JOIN Valves 
                     ON EngineConfig.ValvesID = Valves.Valvesid
                  JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig 
                     ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID = FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
                     JOIN FuelDeliveryType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID = FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
                     JOIN FuelDeliverySubType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID = FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
                     JOIN FuelSystemControlType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID = FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
                     JOIN FuelSystemDesign 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID = FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
                  JOIN Aspiration 
                     ON EngineConfig.AspirationID = Aspiration.AspirationID
                  JOIN CylinderHeadType 
                     ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID = CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
                  JOIN FuelType 
                     ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID = FuelType.FuelTypeID
                  JOIN IgnitionSystemType 
                     ON EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID = IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
                  JOIN Mfr EngineMfr 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID = EngineMfr.MfrID
                  JOIN EngineVersion 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineVersionID = EngineVersion.EngineVersionID
                  JOIN PowerOutput 
                     ON EngineConfig.PowerOutputId = PowerOutput.PowerOutputId


            JOIN VehicleToSpringTypeConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN SpringType 
                  ON VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.SpringTypeConfigID = SpringType.SpringTypeID
            JOIN VehicleToSteeringConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToSteeringConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN SteeringConfig 
                  ON VehicleToSteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID = SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID
                  JOIN SteeringType 
                     ON SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID = SteeringType.SteeringTypeID
                  JOIN SteeringSystem 
                     ON SteeringConfig.SteeringSystemID = SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemID

            JOIN VehicleToTransmission 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToTransmission.VehicleID
               JOIN Transmission 
                  ON VehicleToTransmission.TransmissionID = Transmission.TransmissionID
                  JOIN TransmissionBase 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionBaseID = TransmissionBase.TransmissionBaseID
                     JOIN TransmissionType 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionTypeID = TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeID
                     JOIN TransmissionNumSpeeds 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionNumSpeedsID = TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeedsID
                     JOIN TransmissionControlType 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionControlTypeID = TransmissionControlType.TransmissionControlTypeID
                  JOIN ElecControlled TransElecControlled 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionElecControlledID = TransElecControlled.ElecControlledID
                  JOIN Mfr TransmissionMfr 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrID = TransmissionMfr.MfrID
                  JOIN TransmissionMfrCode 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrCodeID = TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCodeID

            JOIN VehicleToWheelbase 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToWheelbase.VehicleID
               JOIN WheelBase 
                  ON VehicleToWheelbase.WheelbaseID = WheelBase.WheelBaseID

         JOIN Positions 
            ON IAN.position_id = Positions.PositionID
```

Then, after looking at this, I tried to look at what could I possibly turn into "prequery" summary tables -- of which most are based on a vehicle_id.   So, I've created several joins via sub components such as body, brakes, engine, transmission, etc, and came up with...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      IAN.sku,
      IAN.notes,
      Parts.partterminologyname,

      PQBaseVehicle.YearID,
      PQBaseVehicle.MakeName,
      PQBaseVehicle.modelname,
      PQBaseVehicle.VehicleTypeName,
      PQBaseVehicle.VehicleTypeGroupName,

      PQVTrans.TransmissionTypeName,
      PQVTrans.TransmissionNumSpeeds,
      PQVTrans.ElecControlled,
      PQVTrans.MfrName,
      PQVTrans.TransmissionMfrCode,

      PQEngine.Engine,
      PQEngine.Liter,
      PQEngine.CC,
      PQEngine.CID,
      PQEngine.Cylinders,
      PQEngine.BlockType,
      PQEngine.EngBoreIn,
      PQEngine.EngBoreMetric,
      PQEngine.EngStrokeIn,
      PQEngine.EngStrokeMetric,
      PQEngine.EngineDesignationName,
      PQEngine.EngineVINName,
      PQEngine.ValvesPerEngine,
      PQEngine.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
      PQEngine.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
      PQEngine.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
      PQEngine.FuelSystemDesignName,
      PQEngine.AspirationName,
      PQEngine.CylinderHeadTypeName,
      PQEngine.FuelTypeName,
      PQEngine.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
      PQEngine.MfrName,
      PQEngine.EngineVersion,
      PQEngine.HorsePower,
      PQEngine.KilowattPower,

      PQBrakes.FrontBrakeTypeName,
      PQBrakes.RearBrakeTypeName,
      PQBrakes.BrakeSystemName,
      PQBrakes.BrakeABSName,

      PQBody.BodyNumDoors,
      PQBody.BodyTypeName,

      PQBeds.BedLength,
      PQBeds.BedLengthMetric,
      PQBeds.BedTypeName,

      PQSteering.SteeringTypeName,
      PQSteering.SteeringSystemName,

      Submodel.SubmodelName,
      Positions.position,
      DriveType.DriveTypeName,
      SpringType.SpringTypeName,
      WheelBase.WheelBase,
      WheelBase.WheelBaseMetric
   FROM
      Import_AcesApplication_New IAN
         JOIN Parts 
            ON IAN.part_type_id = Parts.PartTerminologyID
         JOIN Positions 
            ON IAN.position_id = Positions.PositionID

         JOIN ( select STRAIGHT_JOIN
                      BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID,
                      BaseVehicle.YearID,
                      Make.MakeName,
                      Model.modelname,
                      VehicleType.VehicleTypeName,
                      VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupName
                   from 
                      BaseVehicle 
                         JOIN Make 
                            ON BaseVehicle.MakeID = Make.MakeID
                            JOIN Model 
                               ON BaseVehicle.ModelID = Model.ModelID
                               JOIN VehicleType 
                                  ON Model.VehicleTypeID = VehicleType.VehicleTypeID
                                  JOIN VehicleTypeGroup 
                                     ON VehicleType.VehicleTypeGroupId = VehicleTypeGroup.VehicleTypeGroupId ) PQBaseVehicle
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = PQBaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID

         JOIN Vehicle 
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
            JOIN Submodel 
               ON Vehicle.SubmodelID = Submodel.SubmodelID

            JOIN VehicleToWheelbase 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToWheelbase.VehicleID
               JOIN WheelBase 
                  ON VehicleToWheelbase.WheelbaseID = WheelBase.WheelBaseID

            JOIN VehicleToDriveType 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToDriveType.VehicleID
               JOIN DriveType 
                  ON VehicleToDriveType.DriveTypeID = DriveType.DriveTypeID

            JOIN VehicleToSpringTypeConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.VehicleID
               JOIN SpringType 
                  ON VehicleToSpringTypeConfig.SpringTypeConfigID = SpringType.SpringTypeID

            JOIN ( SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VSC.VehicleID,
                         ST.SteeringTypeName,
                         SS.SteeringSystemName
                      FROM
                         VehicleToSteeringConfig VSC
                            JOIN SteeringConfig SC
                               ON VSC.SteeringConfigID = SC.SteeringConfigID
                               JOIN SteeringType ST
                                  ON SC.SteeringConfigID = ST.SteeringTypeID
                               JOIN SteeringSystem SS
                                  ON SC.SteeringSystemID = SS.SteeringSystemID ) PQSteering
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQSteering.VehicleID


            JOIN ( SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VBC.VehicleID,
                         BL.BedLength,
                         BL.BedLengthMetric,
                         BT.BedTypeName
                      FROM
                         VehicleToBedConfig VBC
                            ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VBC.VehicleID
                            JOIN BedConfig BC
                               ON VBC.BedConfigID = BC.BedConfigID
                               JOIN BedLength BL
                                  ON BC.BedLengthID = BL.BedLengthID
                               JOIN BedType BT
                                  ON BC.BedTypeID = BT.BedTypeID ) PQBeds
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQBeds.VehicleID


            JOIN ( SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VBSC.VehicleID,
                         BND.BodyNumDoors,
                         BT.BodyTypeName
                      FROM
                         VehicleToBodyStyleConfig VBSC
                            JOIN BodyStyleConfig BSC
                               ON VBSC.BodyStyleConfigID = BSC.BodyStyleConfigID
                               JOIN BodyNumDoors BND
                                  ON BSC.BodyNumDoorsID = BND.BodyNumDoorsID
                               JOIN BodyType BT
                                  ON BSC.BodyTypeID = BT.BodyTypeID ) PQBody
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQBody.VehicleID


            JOIN ( SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VBC.VehicleID,
                         FBT.BrakeTypeName FrontBrakeTypeName,
                         RBT.BrakeTypeName RearBrakeTypeName,
                         BS.BrakeSystemName,
                         BrakeABS.BrakeABSName
                      FROM
                         VehicleToBrakeConfig VBC
                            JOIN BrakeConfig BC
                               ON VBC.BrakeConfigID = BC.BrakeConfigID
                               JOIN BrakeType FBT 
                                  ON BC.FrontBrakeTypeID = FBT.BrakeTypeID
                               JOIN BrakeType RBT
                                  ON BC.RearBrakeTypeID = RBT.BrakeTypeID
                               JOIN BrakeSystem BS
                                  ON BC.BrakeSystemID = BS.BrakeSystemID
                               JOIN BrakeABS 
                                  ON BC.BrakeABSID = BrakeABS.BrakeABSID ) PQBrakes
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQBrakes.VehicleID

            JOIN ( select STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VEC.VehicleID,
                         CONCAT(EB.Cylinders, ' Cyl ', EB.Liter, 'L') as engine,
                         EB.Liter,
                         EB.CC,
                         EB.CID,
                         EB.Cylinders,
                         EB.BlockType,
                         EB.EngBoreIn,
                         EB.EngBoreMetric,
                         EB.EngStrokeIn,
                         EB.EngStrokeMetric,
                         ED.EngineDesignationName,
                         EVIN.EngineVINName,
                         V.ValvesPerEngine,
                         FDT.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
                         FDST.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
                         FSCT.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
                         FSD.FuelSystemDesignName,
                         Asp.AspirationName,
                         CHT.CylinderHeadTypeName,
                         FT.FuelTypeName,
                         IST.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
                         EMFR.MfrName,
                         EVer.EngineVersion,
                         PO.HorsePower,
                         PO.KilowattPower
                      from
                         VehicleToEngineConfig VEC
                            JOIN EngineConfig EC
                               ON VEC.EngineConfigID = EC.EngineConfigID
                               JOIN EngineBase EB
                                  ON EC.EngineBaseID = EB.EngineBaseID
                               JOIN EngineDesignation ED
                                  ON EC.EngineDesignationID = ED.EngineDesignationID
                               JOIN EngineVIN EVIN
                                  ON EC.EngineVINID = EVIN.EngineVINID
                               JOIN Valves V
                                  ON EC.ValvesID = V.Valvesid
                               JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig FDC
                                  ON EC.FuelDeliveryConfigID = FDC.FuelDeliveryConfigID
                                  JOIN FuelDeliveryType FDT
                                     ON FDC.FuelDeliveryTypeID = FDT.FuelDeliveryTypeID
                                  JOIN FuelDeliverySubType FDST
                                     ON FDC.FuelDeliverySubTypeID = FDST.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
                                  JOIN FuelSystemControlType FSCT
                                     ON FDC.FuelSystemControlTypeID = FSCT.FuelSystemControlTypeID
                                  JOIN FuelSystemDesign FSD
                                     ON FDC.FuelSystemDesignID = FSD.FuelSystemDesignID
                               JOIN Aspiration Asp
                                  ON EC.AspirationID = Asp.AspirationID
                               JOIN CylinderHeadType CHT
                                  ON EC.CylinderHeadTypeID = CHT.CylinderHeadTypeID
                               JOIN FuelType FT
                                  ON EC.FuelTypeID = FT.FuelTypeID
                               JOIN IgnitionSystemType IST
                                  ON EC.IgnitionSystemTypeID = IST.IgnitionSystemTypeID
                               JOIN Mfr EMFR
                                  ON EC.EngineMfrID = EMFR.MfrID
                               JOIN EngineVersion EVer
                                  ON EC.EngineVersionID = EVer.EngineVersionID
                               JOIN PowerOutput PO
                                  ON EC.PowerOutputId = PO.PowerOutputId ) PQEngine
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQEngine.VehicleID

            JOIN ( select STRAIGHT_JOIN
                         VTM.VehicleID,
                         TT.TransmissionTypeName,
                         TNS.TransmissionNumSpeeds,
                         TEC.ElecControlled,
                         Mfr.MfrName,
                         TMC.TransmissionMfrCode
                      from 
                         VehicleToTransmission VTM
                            JOIN Transmission T
                               ON VTM.TransmissionID = T.TransmissionID
                               JOIN TransmissionBase TB
                                  ON T.TransmissionBaseID = TB.TransmissionBaseID
                                  JOIN TransmissionType TT
                                     ON TB.TransmissionTypeID = TT.TransmissionTypeID
                                  JOIN TransmissionNumSpeeds TNS
                                     ON TB.TransmissionNumSpeedsID = TNS.TransmissionNumSpeedsID
                                  JOIN TransmissionControlType TCT
                                     ON TB.TransmissionControlTypeID = TCT.TransmissionControlTypeID
                               JOIN ElecControlled TEC 
                                  ON T.TransmissionElecControlledID = TEC.ElecControlledID
                               JOIN Mfr 
                                  ON T.TransmissionMfrID = Mfr.MfrID
                               JOIN TransmissionMfrCode TMC
                                  ON T.TransmissionMfrCodeID = TMC.TransmissionMfrCodeID ) PQVTrans
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = PQVTrans.VehicleID
```

Now, for grins, pre-test each of the PREQUERIES on their own merits to make sure they work, and please make note of how many entries are returned per query.  We may need to do a modified query to get counts per vehicle to see where Cartesian results MAY lie and kill your server memory.  For the subqueries, I also abbreviated the table names to shorten readability some.

```
PQBaseVehicle
PQVTrans
PQEngine
PQBrakes
PQBody
PQBeds
PQSteering
```

**FOR EXAMPLE, the PQSteering, only run THIS part...**

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      VSC.VehicleID,
      ST.SteeringTypeName,
      SS.SteeringSystemName
   FROM
      VehicleToSteeringConfig VSC
         JOIN SteeringConfig SC
            ON VSC.SteeringConfigID = SC.SteeringConfigID
            JOIN SteeringType ST
               ON SC.SteeringConfigID = ST.SteeringTypeID
            JOIN SteeringSystem SS
               ON SC.SteeringSystemID = SS.SteeringSystemID
```

I'm out for the night and will check in tomorrow some to see if I can help with follow-up.

Comment: I've added a single WHERE ('WHERE BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID = 2938'), and received: (258880 total, Query took 0.1388 sec). I have added your cover indexes as originally instructed, which have helped, I'm sure.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, I can see why you are probably blowing away your server.  You have over 73.5 Million records... that and getting all the descriptions from the corresponding lookup tables, not counting what would be needed in memory for the indexes, joining, etc...  I would try sampling both my queries, but do for a single model year and see if at least THAT will run without choking your server.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, additionally, per your base vehicle test, try a simple select count(*) from Import_AcesApplication_New IAN where IAN.base_vehicle_id = 2938 and see if that alone matches your 258880... if not, then you also have issue with Cartesian results, thus multiplying the magnitude of your putput.